# Wrong path for css/js on symfony route with argument

Tags: php, css, symfony, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4.4. 
I have a controller who have differents routes...

One of them have a token on arguments like this :

```
/**
 * @Route("/activation/{token}", name="activation")
 */
public function activation(...
```

For this route and only this one, my css  dosn't load because the path is wrong:

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/activation/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

When i remove then{token} argument from my route my css loaded.

For my template i declare css like this on my base.html.twig:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="{{ asset('css/style.css')}}" />#}
```

Anyone have any idea why asset function render dynamique path ?

Comment: do you have a base uri/path set in your html? also, can you please check what is exactly in the output html? (view source in browser)

Comment: Try changing your CSS style path to `/css/style.css` or `/css/activation.css`, because the current path is conflicting with your controller route.

Comment: @Leprechaun according to docs, without the leading slash is the correct way. I assume there's some base path/uri stuff going on that moves this to another base path, since it also only happens on this page ...

Comment: @Jakumi In template everything is correct, I think you need to check Asset config

Answer (score -1):

You can add Requirement for your route with a regular expression which will exclude *css* name from token argument.